# How to change icon on React Native Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

This code help me get current position and draw marker.

```
    async componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    ....

        this.setState({
          location,
          region: {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0143,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0134
          }
        });
      }, //ok
      () => {}, //error
      {
        timeout: 2000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 1000
      }
    );
  }

  handleLocationSelected = (data, { geometry }) => {
    const {
      location: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }
    } = geometry;

    this.setState({
      destination: {
        latitude,
        longitude,
        title: data.structured_formatting.main_text
      }
    });
  };
.....

<Marker
                coordinate={destination}
                anchor={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                image="marker.png";
              >
```

How I can change icon on Google map marker ?

I tried add `image:"maker.png";` but I must click or touch on it, the marker change.

UPDATE:
I Updated my post.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the marker? The code you posted only sets the region

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<MapView.Marker
     image={require('./maker.png')}
     anchor={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
     coordinate={destination}>
</MapView.Marker>,
```